# Why doesn't scikit-cuda subtract broadcast like numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, gpu

skcuda.misc.subtract is not broadcasting as I expected. With this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import skcuda.misc as gpumisc
import pycuda.autoinit

a = np.ones((3, 1))
b = np.ones((1, 3))
c = a - b
assert np.allclose(c, np.zeros((3, 3)))

a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(a)
b_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(b)
c_gpu = gpumisc.subtract(a_gpu, b_gpu)
assert np.allclose(c_gpu.get(), np.zeros((3, 3)))
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-63f3109ba0df> in <module>()
     11 a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(a)
     12 b_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(b)
---> 13 c_gpu = gpumisc.subtract(a_gpu, b_gpu)
     14 assert np.allclose(c_gpu.get(), np.zeros((3, 3)))

/appl/pm/vendor/dev/python/lx-x86_64/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skcuda/misc.pyc in subtract(x_gpu, y_gpu)
   1032     """
   1033 
-> 1034     return binaryop_2d("-", operator.sub, False, x_gpu, y_gpu)
   1035 
   1036 def multiply(x_gpu, y_gpu):

/appl/pm/vendor/dev/python/lx-x86_64/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skcuda/misc.pyc in binaryop_2d(c_op, py_op, commutative, x_gpu, y_gpu)
    982             return binaryop_matvec(c_op, y_gpu, x_gpu.ravel(), axis=0)
    983 
--> 984     raise TypeError("unsupported combination of shapes")
    985 
    986 def add(x_gpu, y_gpu):

TypeError: unsupported combination of shapes
```

Anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

(I can't seem to post without writing more words. Tomorrow and tomorrow and tomorrow creeps in this petty pace from day to day to the last syllable of recorded time...)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not bound to scikit-cuda, I'd suggest using TensorFlow for CUDA backend. It supports broadcasting natively on many of its operators. For your example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = np.ones((3, 1)) 
b = np.ones((1, 3))
c = a - b
assert np.allclose(c, np.zeros((3, 3)))

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    a_gpu = tf.constant(a)
    b_gpu = tf.constant(b)
    c_gpu = tf.sub(a_gpu, b_gpu)

sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False))
c_gpu_out = sess.run(c_gpu)

np.testing.assert_allclose(c_gpu_out, np.zeros((3, 3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The memory model of cuda (and GPUs generally) makes arbitrary broadcasting operations a very unappealing proposition. Only contiguous reads/writes are efficient; so your threads should align along a contiguous stride. This makes it very difficult to write a general broadcasting function that will not produce horribly suboptimal performance under many circumstances.

Comment: Thank you. How do I align along a contiguous stride to get my simple example to work?

Comment: This is flat out wrong, infact, the memory model of GPUS actually makes broadcasting a better proposition, because you touch less memory (instead of having to needlessly upload and populate a bunch of duplicate entries), scikit cuda doesn't do it because the authors never bothered to implement it, not because of special hardware considerations.  Contiguous read/write also applies to CPU code.

Comment: Not I said 'arbitrary broadcasting operations'. Generating a kernel thats no worse than acting on dense arrays for the simple scenario in the OP indeed should be easy. Actually realising the theoretical benefit of the lack of dense arrays is not as trivial though. Having all threads in a warp hit the same memory location takes exactly as much time as just reading the entire contiguous range; there is literally zero benefit there. You can realize a benefit; but realizing it for the general case is not easy; but it is pretty easy to make it worse.